# Probability of getting a mirror image

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

In a suitable font, the letters A, H, I, M, O, T, U, V, W, X, and Y are all mirror images of themselves. A string made from these letters will be a mirror image of itself if it reads the same backward and forward: for example, MOM, YUMMUY, MOTHTOM. If a four-letter string in these letters is chosen at random, what is the probability that this string is a mirror image of itself?

Comment: You should really say something about what you've tried, but here's a hint: how many letters of a palindrome do you need to know to determine what the palindrome is?

Comment: @RobArthan OP did talk about what they tried, but it was in a comment to a deleted (and now alive again and re-edited) answer.

Comment: The answers below don't make sense: for some bizarre reason, both David and user46944 disallow palindromes like $MMMM$ but allow strings like $MUMU$. (The right answer is $11^{-2}$.)

Comment: @RobArthan You're absolutely right.  I deleted my answer.  Of course $MMMM$ is a mirror image word.

Comment: Rob Arthan - MUMU is not a mirror image but MUUM is.

Comment: From the examples and the word reads, it is not clear if at least one vowel is required or not.  All the examples have vowels.

Comment: OP is not asking for mirror image words, rather mirror image strings.  What is not clear to me is if at least one vowel needs to be present or not.  It would have been better if one example didn't have any for clarity such as AAAA.

Comment: @David: $MUMU$ needs to be counted in the sample space as a non-palindrome. The answers (now removed or corrected) that I was commenting on included $MUMU$ in the sample space but didn't include $MMMM$ as a palindrome.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$121 / 11^4$ seems right to me.

Comment: wouldn't it be (11*10*1*1) / (11*11*11*11) because there are only 11 letter choices?

Comment: I don't see why you are mixing selection with and without replacement. The answer should surely be $11^{-2}$. See my comment on the question.

Comment: 121/11^4 = 1/11.  Which I think is right.  But an answer without an explanation seems .... to miss the point.

Comment: 121/11^4 is not 1/11.

Answer (score 1):

The first two letters can be anything.

The third letter must be the same as the 2nd.  That's 1/11.

The fourth letter must be the same as the 1st.  That's 1/11.

So the probability is $1/11^2 = 1/121$.